# How do I get fb0 scanline length?

Tags: linux, framebuffer

I am accessing /dev/fb0, the screen's frame buffer, in console mode, Debian 10, using a HP Envy Touchsmart laptop, using fwrite standard C function.

I read this page:
https://techoverflow.net/2015/06/21/querying-framebuffer-resolution-in-linux/

It states that "cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size" should return fb0's dimensions.

It returns 1366 x 768 pixels. This is my actual screen resolution. So good so far.

But when I write into /dev/fb0, I actually need to write 1376 pixels before I start a new row.

Please note pixels are 32-bit packets, so it does not look like there is an underlying scanline alignment issue. We are talking about a difference of 10 times 4 bytes, i.e. 40 bytes, which is a lot.

Where does this discrepancy come from?
How do I get the scanline width information without having to find out visually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably find the value in `/sys/class/graphics/fb0/stride` which is the *length of the line in bytes* according to the [source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.17/source/include/uapi/linux/fb.h#L168). You need to divide by the `bits_per_pixel` divided by 8 to get the [stride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stride_of_an_array) in pixels.

Comment: Brilliant! I ended up finding about fb.h and ioctl calls, but your answer is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't this information be in the `fb_var_screeninfo` object returned by the `ioctl`? It's conveniently missing...